# React Babel Core Module Not Found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I was learning React.js by following some video tutorial. It was working fine but today I continued the work and added state to my component and suddenly after saving I am getting `babel-core` error.
I am new to React so I can't understand what error is this, and I think it's not related with changing of components I made today.
I have also uploaded my project till this point on github [here](https://github.com/sachuverma/The-Burger-Builder)

On webpage I get this error message -

```
Failed to compile

./node_modules/babel-core/lib/helpers/resolve.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'module' in 'C:\Users\Sachin Verma\Desktop\WebD work\React\The Burger Builder\node_modules\babel-core\lib\helpers'
```

In console I get this long error -

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "module"
    at webpackMissingModule (resolve.js:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (resolve.js:34)
    at Object../node_modules/babel-core/lib/helpers/resolve.js (resolve.js:46)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:678)
    at fn (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:88)
    at Object../node_modules/babel-core/lib/helpers/resolve-from-possible-names.js (resolve-from-possible-names.js:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:678)
    at fn (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:88)
    at Object.<anonymous> (resolve-plugin.js:6)
    at Object../node_modules/babel-core/lib/helpers/resolve-plugin.js (resolve-plugin.js:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:678)
    at fn (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:88)
    at Object.<anonymous> (option-manager.js:43)
    at Object../node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js (option-manager.js:383)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:678)
    at fn (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:88)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:42)
    at Object../node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js (index.js:737)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:678)
    at fn (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:88)
    at Object../node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/node.js (node.js:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:678)
    at fn (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:88)
    at Object../node_modules/babel-core/index.js (index.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:678)
    at fn (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:88)
    at Object../src/components/Burger/Burger.js (Burger.css:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:678)
    at fn (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:88)
    at Object../src/containers/BurgerBuilder/BurgerBuilder.js (Layout.js:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:678)
    at fn (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:88)
    at Object../src/App.js (fetch.js:461)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:678)
    at fn (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:88)
    at Object../src/index.js (index.css?f255:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:678)
    at fn (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:88)
    at Object.0 (registerServiceWorker.js:117)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:678)
    at bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:724
    at bootstrap 8d64744152fbd1b327ed:724
```

```
index.js:2178 ./node_modules/babel-core/lib/helpers/resolve.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'module' in 'C:\Users\Sachin Verma\Desktop\WebD work\React\The Burger Builder\node_modules\babel-core\lib\helpers'
```

Update:
I ran `npm run eject` to add some configs so that class names in component's css files do not clash with each other.
I added these two lines.

[image: configs updated screenshot]

Comment: The `babel-core` package is over 2 years old. I'm sure you didn't just "add state to your component" for it to be suddenly referenced.

Comment: Based on the last commit in your repo, you've maybe run `react-scripts eject`? Why?

Comment: The video I was following, that person run eject command then edited `webpack.config.dev.js` file in config directory so because even if we have css in different files for each component still they will clash with each other so after adding some configuration each css classes will have some random characters added to the classes defined in css file based on file location or something i guess so that no two different css class will clash. I have uploaded the screenshot of two lines which were added.

Comment: The tutorial is using an older version of CRA then; CRA 2.0.0+ supports CSS modules out of the box. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/
Ejecting is an expert feature you shouldn't use, basically ever.

Comment: I made a PR in your repo that fixes these things. https://github.com/sachuverma/The-Burger-Builder/pull/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular error is caused by [you having inadvertently added this import](https://github.com/sachuverma/The-Burger-Builder/blob/44d085484e25c17c6ab58ed7493f6e086525325d/src/components/Burger/Burger.js#L1) from the `babel-core` library you don't have installed:

```
import { transform } from 'babel-core';
```

Remove the line and you're good to go.

However, I still wonder why you've done `react-scripts eject` in your repo...

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem!

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have taken the Maximilian class of React on Udemy and you encountered this issue in section 8 - Lesson 129. This is because when you tried to create the variable transformedIngredient you might have got a suggestion of transform keyword which is reserved keyword in babel-core that got imported on the top of your js file. Remove that and you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem!